# In filter pane the dim table fields have a 1 next to it instead of a count of rows in equiv fact table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Using Power BI and the table visual and needing to show fields from both the fact and dimension tables. When I add my fields to the table visual they shpw fine but the dimension fields in the filter pane have a 1 next to each value instead of the count of rows in the equivalent fact table. If i import a fact table with left joins then it shows the right count of values does anyone have a way how to best show columns from dim/fact tables in a table visual.

p.s I don't see the point in a star schema when there is these kind of problems appearing.

Sample Data

Sales Table

```
sales_id    sales    sales_person    date_sold    product_id
1            5000      john          10/01/2022       1
2            7000      john          10/01/2022       2
3            5000      bill          10/01/2022       1
4            7000      bill          11/01/2022       2
5            5000      john          11/02/2022       1
```

product table

```
product_id    product          category_id
1             kitchen units       kitchen
2             floor tiles        flooring
```

expected/desired output

table visual

```
sales_id      sales     sales_person     date_sold      product
 1            5000         john          10/01/2022     kitchen units
 2            7000         john          10/01/2022     floor tiles
 3            5000         bill          10/01/2022     kitchen units
 4            7000         bill          11/01/2022     floor tiles
 5            5000         john          11/02/2022     kitchen units
```

click on table visual then view filter pane

```
example of two fields

sales_person
john             3
bill             2

product
kitchen units    1
floor tiling     1
```

Why does the above product field show only a one? I understand its because its a dim field but would prefer to see

product

```
kitchen units     3
floor tiles       2
```

An example in relation to my question:

[image]

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Also new to power bi. But maybe you could get the name from Product and count from Sales.
[image]

[image]

For this to work you need table relation:
[image]

Comment: sorry not what I was looking for I'll add an image of the problem I am having of the filter pane

Comment: When you look at the filter for the product table. That table only has one of each.  While the Sales table has more. It does not take into account any possible relations.